# My existing flask application fails to run via apache server if I add statement import matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, flask

I am on windows 10 and working with python 3.10
I have a flask application that renders an html file with data from postgresql
I am running it through an apache server.( httpd)
I have a web.wsgi, and it runs perfect

Now I want to add a route to the flask application to create charts. I have added the following example to try out.
It loads if I run flask as an application, and I can see the chart too in  http://127.0.0.1:5000/print-plot

However when I try to run the same application through apache server ( httpd) even the base page does not load . It takes forever( localhost:80 is not loading).

By eliminating,  I realized that just the statement
**import matplotlib**
, is preventing the base html page from loading through apache( **though independently running the flask app works**)
If I comment **import matplotlib**           the page loads
**Where am I going wrong?**
This is the approute  example I used for matplotlibhttps://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-show-matplotlib-in-flask
Adding the following to my existing flask code made it available through directly running flask but made the base page failing to load via apache

```
import io
from flask import Response
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/print-plot')
def plot_png():
   fig = Figure()
   axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
   xs = np.random.rand(100)
   ys = np.random.rand(100)
   axis.plot(xs, ys)
   output = io.BytesIO()
   FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
   return Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')
```

This runs perfectly fine if I run the flask app independently. The chart in fact loads in

However if I try to runthe apache server ( httpd

Comment: Make sure you understand the different [Matplotlib backends](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) for different scenarios. An educated guess is that you want to use `agg` for your situation.

Comment: This works fine if i execute the app as a standalone. I am only facing problem when I run it from apache server. removing import matplotlib from the flask app, allows it to be rendered by apache. There seems to be something that apache needs for matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

This solution if for windows in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` add the following line after `WSGIScriptAlias` statement

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```